# Keyboard flashes from opaque to transparent upon push

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view embedded in a navigation and tab bar controller. When a button is pressed, it pushes to (shows) the next view and I programmed the keyboard to immediately show for the first text field `[textField becomeFirstResponder]`.

However, the keyboard will be opaque instantly then turn transparent in a little less than half a second. This happens no matter the keyboard type or keyboard look. I have no idea what is causing this, and I cannot find any answers anywhere else.

Other details: the navigation bar is translucent, and the bottom bar is hidden on the view we push to. The background is an image. This problem does not occur if I remove `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` and have the user just select the text field, but that is not what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar scenario and also ran into this issue.

I am push-segueing between view controllers, and the keyboard has to stay up during the segue (`textField.becomeFirstResponder()` is called in `viewWillAppear(_:)`). The view controllers' background is white, but the keyboard look is `Dark`. During the segue, the keyboard is black, and then turns gray as soon as the segue finishes.

I came up with a workaround for that - it works if you want to have the keyboard opaque-ish at all times.

Add an empty `UIView` to the view controllers where you want to show the keyboard instantly, and set the `backgroundColor` of the view to match your keyboard's look (black for `Dark`, white for `Light`). Pin that view to left, right and bottom edges of the view controller's <strike>safe area</strike> superview. Add a height constraint to it equal to 0 and make an `IBOutlet` for it.

In your view controller, subscribe to `KeyboardWillShow` and `KeyboardWillHide` notifications and control the height constraint of the view you created - make it match the keyboard's frame height (the keyboard's frame end).

You will still see that during the segue, the keyboard stays opaque, but when the segue finishes and keyboard transparency kicks in, the effect is much less visible.

Ideal scenario for me would be to be able to turn off the transparency of the keyboard completely, but I don't think it's possible. I also think there is no way to make the keyboard non-opaque during the segue, so the only option is to make it look opaque at all times.

Comment: I have the same issue and I called textField.becomeFirstResponder() in the viewDidAppear to resolve it